# How to write unit test for Android ViewModel & LiveData?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, android-livedata

I have my viewmodel and repository like these:

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.filterNotNull
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MyViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val repository: MyRepository
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val myLiveData: LiveData<String> = repository.getDataFlow().filterNotNull().asLiveData()

    fun loadData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.fetchNewData()
        }
    }
}

class MyRepository {
    // A Flow that emits data
    private val _dataFlow = MutableStateFlow<String>("initial value")

    fun getDataFlow(): Flow<String> = _dataFlow

    suspend fun fetchNewData() {
        for(i in 1..10) {
            // Here you could fetch new data and update the _dataFlow
            println("value-$i")
            _dataFlow.emit("value-$i")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
}
```

and the unit test is like this:

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import com.ford.digital_owners_manual.viewmodels.MyRepository
import com.ford.digital_owners_manual.viewmodels.MyViewModel
import io.mockk.coVerify
import io.mockk.mockk
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.StandardTestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(
    val dispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {
    val testScope = TestScope(dispatcher)
    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // Reset Dispatchers.Main to the original Main dispatcher
    }
}


@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MyViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel
    private lateinit var repository: MyRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        repository = MyRepository()
        viewModel = MyViewModel(
            application = mockk<Application>(),
            repository
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `loadData should update live data value`() = coroutineRule.testScope.runTest {
        val observer: Observer<String> = mockk(relaxed = true)

        // When
        viewModel.myLiveData.observeForever(observer)
        viewModel.loadData()

        runBlocking {
            launch {
                repository.fetchNewData()
            }
            //coVerify { observer.onChanged(any())}
        }
        // Then
        assertEquals("Sample Data", viewModel.myLiveData.getOrAwaitValue())
        coVerify { observer.onChanged(any())}
        //verify { repository.getDataFlow() }
    }
}
```

`getOrAwaitValue` is defined here, copied from other SO answers.

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }

    this.observeForever(observer)

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```

`coVerify` says `observer.onChanged(any())` never called.
`assertEquals` complains `LiveData` value was never set.